# Segwit2x and Trezor

Tags: trezor, segwit2x

I got my bitcoin in my Trezor cold wallet. Before the imminent implementation of Segwit2x I have to do something in my Trezor, can this affect my BTC?

I look forward to your help, thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from an answer given by a Trezor's staff member in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TREZOR/comments/74f70w/how_will_the_segwit2x_fork_work_on_trezor/) on 5th October 2017:

> We will do an official communication once it is clear what Segwit2x is and what is not. Currently, there are some changes in the Segwit2x queue which might or might not be accepted and this can change significantly what steps would need to be done.

**UPDATE** This is the official [Trezor Statement on Segwit2X Hard Fork](https://blog.trezor.io/trezor-statement-segwit2x-2x-hard-fork-b2x-f245fe4f0fb) :)

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.trezor.io/trezor-statement-segwit2x-2x-hard-fork-b2x-f245fe4f0fb

No, it can be done later.

"If you have held BTC on your TREZOR before the fork, you will own the same amount of BTC and B2X after the fork."